# GCP structured logging, works locally but not on kubernetes

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, logging

I'm trying to create structured logging on GCP from my service. When I run it locally I manage to get JsonPayload in the correct format as shown bellow:

```
jsonPayload: {
exception: {
Message: ""
StackTrace: ""
TargetSite: ""
Type: "value_error"
}
logging.googleapis.com/labels: {2}
logging.googleapis.com/spanId: "94ecf8a83efd7f34"
logging.googleapis.com/trace: "dc4696d790ab643b058f87dbeebf19a3"
message: "Bad Request"
severity: "ERROR"
time: "2022-10-05T14:38:52.965749Z"
```

but when I run the service on Kubernetes I only get the following in the logging:

```
jsonPayload: {
exception: {
Message: ""
StackTrace: ""
TargetSite: ""
Type: "value_error"
}
message: "Bad Request"
```

Why is GCP removing logging.googleapis.com/labels, logging.googleapis.com/spanId,logging.googleapis.com/trace, severity from the logging JsonPayload when I run the service on GCP kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *may* be working-as-intended (WAI) but it's unclear from your question.

Google [Structured Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging) attempts to parse log entries as JSON and extracts specific fields including `logging.googleapis.com/labels`.

However (!) when it does this, some of these fields including `logging.googleapis.com/labels` are **relocated** from the [`jsonPayload`](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#FIELDS.json_payload) field to another [`LogEntry`](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#FIELDS.span_id) field.

See:

- [labels](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#FIELDS.labels)
- [spanId](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#FIELDS.span_id)
- [trace](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#FIELDS.trace)

So, you should not look for these values in `jsonPayload` in Cloud Logging but in e.g. `labels`, `spanId` and `trace`:

```bash
PROJECT=...

# Filter by entries that contain `jsonPayload`
gcloud logging read "jsonPayload:*" \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(jsonPayload,labels,spanId,trace)"
```

Comment: Yes, this was it 

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it!